# How do I change Office 2013 colors to look like Office 2010?

Tags: microsoft-office-2013

I'm not a fan of the themes offered by Office 2013 (White, Light Gray, Dark Gray). Office 2010 has more contrast and is easier on the eyes. Is there any way to add an "Office 2010"-like theme to Office 2013?

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-office_install/how-to-change-the-theme-of-office-2013/aadcf2ff-4435-48e1-bc80-c058d6299a61?tab=question&status=AllReplies#tabs

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not the answer you want but pick Dark Gray and give it some time. That's the only way I found.