# Office 2013 with Windows 7 theme

Tags: windows-7, themes, microsoft-office-2013

I have just installed Office 2013, and I noticed that it does not use the operating system’s chrome/theme, in this case Windows 7.

Before I uninstall and go back to Office 2010, can a setting be changed such that Office 2013 uses the operating system’s theme, and not its own?

Comment: Unlikely the visual look was one of the major changes in 2013

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/628388/how-do-i-change-office-2013-colors-to-look-like-office-2010

Comment: @Ramhound nailed it, you're probably better off getting used to it, or switching, as it's the new look of MS Office.  The subtle GPU accelerated effects in 2013 are way cool. ;)

Comment: Stay at Office 2010. The UI of 2013 is so horrible. My eyes ache all the time I use it.

Comment: As my workmate said, "Embrace the ... pastel, it's the future". No provision for UI customization is made except for background decoration of the ribbon. As is Windows 8, so is Office 2013. Large areas of screen space wasted. Ugly color contrasts that can be hard on the eyes.

Comment: I don't think it's the future, more like a temporary blip until MS regains their senses. Just like Windows 8 and Vista.