# Window Color and Appearance removed in Win10?

Tags: windows-10, color-theme

I just upgraded my PC to Win10 but cannot find the dialog "Window Color and Appearance". In Win7, it should be at: `Control Panel => Appearance and Personalization => Personalization => Window Color and Appearance`, and it looks like:

[image: Window Color and Appearance]

How can I access it in Win10?

Comment: I don't think that exact option exists anymore in Windows 10 but there is a similar workaround: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3380-color-appearance-change-windows-10-a.html

Comment: There is no way to change this like in Windows 7, however see this answer here: http://superuser.com/a/1078778/128359

Comment: duplicate of: https://superuser.com/questions/1002847/how-to-change-default-window-background-color-in-windows-10/1078778#1078778

Comment: was this removed because it was not dumb-proof ? meh. I will try pulling the cpl file from windows 7 like i did the calculator and see if it works.

Answer (score 24):

Although the Window Color and Appearance dialog is no longer available, you can still edit the underlying registry settings in **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors**

---

**Edit**
Recently, I have found this setting is not working but have found that
**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\Colors** is working.

---

[image: Window Color and Appearance Registry]

For example, change your background color from white to grey by changing the **Window** property from **255 255 255** to **160 160 160**

The three numbers in each entry are the RGB (Red, Green, Blue) codes for the color required. Each number can be any value from 0 to 255 to allow you to choose any of over 16 million colors.  For example, white is **255 255 255**, red is **255 0 0**, blue is **0 0 255**. Please note that there is a single space between each number.

You can get help with the colors using an online color picker such as [www.colorpicker.com](http://www.colorpicker.com), selecting the color you want and making a note of the RGB codes and then entering them into the registry setting.

I found a computer restart was required though a log off/on again may suffice for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Is there anywhere an explanation of what each setting does?

Comment: There's [another](https://superuser.com/questions/1386302/how-to-replace-the-desktop-background-image-with-a-solid-color-using-powershell/1386333#1386333) Reg location that also contain the same items. Any idea what is the difference? `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\Colors`

Comment: Recently, I have found that HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors is NOT working but that HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\Colors is working.

Answer (score 6):

[Classic Color Panel](https://www.wintools.info/index.php/classic-color-panel) gives you a GUI to control many of the values in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors`.

[image]

But, as the author notes, for Windows 10 "Unfortunately, the settings of Classic Color Panel do not always have an impact on the actually displayed image elements."

In my experience, it makes almost no difference to the total mess of Windows 10 color control.

Comment: I tested.  It works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look: [Color and Appearance shortcut - Create in Windows 10](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5848-color-appearance-shortcut-create-windows-10-a.html)

> Windows 10 includes a new black system theme across the Start menu,
>   Taskbar, and Action Center. There is now support for AutoColor which
>   pulls the primary color from your desktop background.
>
> By default, you can choose a color for your Start menu accents, Start
>   button, taskbar, buttons, text, Settings accents, sign-in screen
>   accents, and Action Center accents in the Settings app now.
>
> The old Color and Appearance Control Panel will also let you change
>   the color intensity and includes a color mixer to let you have a wider
>   choice of colors to select from than you can in Settings.
>
> This tutorial will show you **how to download or create a Color and
>   Appearance shortcut** that opens to the old Control Panel method to
>   change colors for your account in Windows 10.

[image]

1. Click/tap on the Download button below to download [the .zip file](http://www.tenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/18379d1430709455-color-appearance-shortcut-create-windows-10-a-color_and_appearance_shortcut.zip).
2. Save the .zip file to your desktop.
3. Unblock the .zip file.
4. Open the .zip file, and extract (drag and drop) the shortcut to your desktop.
5. If you like, you can Pin to Taskbar, Pin to Start, add to All apps, add to Quick Launch, assign a keyboard shortcut to, or move this shortcut to where you like for easy use.
6. When finished, you can delete the downloaded .zip file if you like.

Comment: Shortcut points to: `%windir%\System32\rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL desk.cpl,Advanced,@Advanced`

Comment: Yes, it's correct. You can ether download or create the shortcut by yourself using this link.

Comment: It seems the shortcut you provided can only access the window you listed, but cannot access the dialog I listed in my question.

Comment: So there is no way to customize the window color in Win10, just like the picture I listed, where I would like to change the background color of all the window from white to light yellow, right?

Comment: No, IMHO there is no other way apart of the dialog I've pointed in my answer.

Comment: LINK DOES NOT WORK.

Answer (score 1):

I found another answer which seems to work better, mainly because the above script does not work properly on my computer. Colour saturation and intensity actually change a turqoise colour to a navy blue when slider is at minimum position, rather than making the colour less intense or less saturated.

Here is what I found on another thread:
Just create a batch file (.BAT) using notepad, which has the following command-line command in it

```
control /name Microsoft.Personalization /page pageWallpaper
```

So I took the above command and created a file called "Desktop Customer Colors.bat" and placed it (or a shortcut that points to it) on my Windows 10 desktop.  This opens the following window:

Change background color:

[image: On this screen select "change background colour"]

Here is the color palette:

[image: Here is the colour palette]

Comment: this feature no longer goes to the legacy control panel in the Creators Update.

Comment: DOES NOT WORK anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

In case you just want to change **application background color ONLY** (e.g. Microsoft Word) and leave other settings untouched, please see another Super User question: [How to change default window background color in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1002847/how-to-change-default-window-background-color-in-windows-10) and read [the answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1002847/how-to-change-default-window-background-color-in-windows-10/1078778#1078778) by Vinayak to create a .theme file to make that change.

Comment: You should quote the relevant information so a reader like myself doesn't have to go to another link.