# Windows 10 equivalent to Windows 7's "Window Color and Appearance"

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, colors

My boss showed us an [article](http://www.daossoft.com/operating-system-tips/how-to-protect-your-eyes-form-computer-screen.html) that explained that the best color background was a subtle green. This was confirmed in r/[Accounting](https://www.reddit.com/r/Accounting/comments/5nklrt/how_to_adjust_screen_color_scheme/) of Reddit.

The process for Windows 7 is to click “Personalize” > “Window Color and Appearance” > “Advanced” > “Item” [dropdown menu] > “Window” > “Color 1” [dropdown menu] > “Other”

Set colors to:

> Hue - 85, Sat - 123, Lum – 205

Is there a way to do this in Windows 10? I've been searching articles, but most suggest using an external .zip file to import. Sadly, I can't do that because my company does not allow admin privileges to employees.

Please help me (and my colleagues).

Comment: What are you trying to change? The background of an application, the desktop background, something else?

Comment: It's possible, but very *very* hacky. Try the answers here: https://superuser.com/questions/1002847/how-to-change-default-window-background-color-in-windows-10

Comment: @music2myear specifically the background of an excel sheet to not be displayed as white on default, but this hue provided. Likewise, Windows 7 would do this for all white back-dropped windows.

Comment: Then we'll probably need to know what version of Office you're running too.

Comment: this dialog was removed in Windows 8

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 has more limited color scheming options than Windows 7 at this point.

The available color selection is performed in **Start** > **Settings** > **Personalization** > **Colors**.

UPDATE: Adding colorization information for Excel

For Excel you can create a template (.xltx file) so that every NEW excel spreadsheet you open will begin with a default colored background.

1. Create an image file of the desired shade in **MSPAINT** or similar. Save this file to your computer somewhere.
2. Open Excel and create a new spreadsheet.
3. In the **Page Layout** tab, in the **Page Setup** group, click **Background**.
4. Select the image file you created previously and click **Insert**.
5. Save this file as an Excel Template (.xltx) file.

*Note: When you select the Excel Template file type in the Save As Type dropdown, you should be automatically taken to the Excel Custom Office Templates folder.*

To apply this template:

- **When adding a new sheet to an existing workbook, or after opening a new workbook:** right-click on the Sheet1 tab and select **Insert**, then select the template you saved. This will insert a new tab with the template applied.
- **When creating a new workbook:** Open Excel, select File > New, click **Personal** and then select your template.

More information and uses can be found here: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win016.htm

Answer (score -1):

1) Hit the windows key + R, opening the run program

2) Type "regedit" to open the registry editor. This is dangerous and normally you should do it only if you are an advanced user and know what you are doing.

3) Click "yes" when Windows asks you if want to allow the program to make changes.

4) Open HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Control Panel > Colors. You should see a long list on the right, including "Windows" and probably the numbers 181 229 181. These are the RGB values for the color.

5) Click Windows and type in any numbers you like. I chose 181 229 181 which gives a nice funky green color.

6) Restart your computer to allow the changes to take effect.