# How to make regedit dark in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

How to make **regedit** dark in windows 10 ?
**regedit** window is not dark in dark mode

I searched about it but only find answers for How to enable dark  mode in windows 10 using  **regedit**?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.  Please edit your question and clarity, what exactly, you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: As it is a rather old tool and one you won't usually touch without good reason it simply might not support it. You could try [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1002847/how-to-change-default-window-background-color-in-windows-10).