# Change background color in Windows 10 without running explorer.exe on startup (winlogon/shell)

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry

This is for iot project and i do not want the explorer bar shown.

I have set value of Shell from explorer.exe to null so it will not run explorer.exe on startup.

I set through registry:
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon

However at the same time my background color change to black. Is there any way to change the background color without running explorer.exe?

[Below is where i set null in registry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgNj2.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this can help you, but I found it from an old topic.

[image]

[image]

> [How to change default window background color in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1002847/how-to-change-default-window-background-color-in-windows-10)

In this, there is a same issue like you that they want to change the background color of Windows 10 as it always displays black.

The answer is too long, so please check at that old topic and try, maybe it can help you!

Comment: The desktop windows in Windows has NOTHING to do with the Window's Explorer desktop. Explorer places its folder window of the user's icons over the top of the old Windows desktop. Set the colour in control panel.