# Change window color in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Which registry entry do I need to modify to change my window color from white (which kills my eyes) to light gray (200, 200, 200)?

I've tried several, including:

- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors\Window`
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors\Background`
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\Colors\Window`

but none seems to have any effect.

[image: window color]

Comment: you mean the Notepad background color? that's not the window color

Comment: Notepad is just an example. Whatever it is called, which registry entry is it?

Comment: I don't know, but if that option is available then it only affects apps that use the default textbox. Did you try restarting or logging out after setting those values? But looks like there's a duplicate: [How to change default window background color in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/q/1002847/241386)

Comment: See if this works for you....https://superuser.com/a/949922/40928

Comment: Use the first method: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors\Window   Restart your computer after changing the Value data. I have tested that on two different virtual machines and they all work.

Comment: Thanks @S.Leon, restart was the step that was missing (not sure if logging out would be enough), now it works.

Comment: @Danijel You're welcome. Glad to hear it works.

Comment: @S.Leon Could you add that as answer?

Comment: Follow the methods in [here](https://superuser.com/a/1190188/116221).

Answer (score 3):

[S.Leon](https://superuser.com/questions/1360841/change-window-color-in-windows-10#comment2044874_1360841) is correct:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors]
"Window"="200 200 200"
```

[Classic Color Panel](https://www.wintools.info/index.php/classic-color-panel-window) is a handy tool for changing this and other system colour settings.

Comment: And: restart is needed.

Comment: And: 230 is better, 200 is too dark. :-) Restart again...

Comment: Not sure about before, but now Classic Color Panel is no longer free. After 30 days it requires activation to apply the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Annoyingly they took the feature that let you do this in Win7 out for Win10.

The closest I can think of would be to enable the "High Contrast" setting and then customize the colours to your preference. To do this go Control Panel -> Appearance and Personalisation -> High Contrast Settings.